# Is it safe to write to a descriptor after ENOSPC

Tags: c, unix, file-io

Imagine this situation:

- one process (A) continuously writes data to disk by creating large files, to which it appends data using separate write() commands
- another process (B), continuously deletes files from disk
- the assumption is that (B) deletes data fast enough that (A) has room to write. However, it is not guaranteed.
- Imagine (A) attempts a write to an open descriptor and it gets ENOSPC. Since (A) knows that (B) should make some room, (A) would like to retry the write.

Question: is it safe for (A), after receiving ENOSPC, to attempt a write on the same descriptor it got ENOSPC on? I couldn't find any information about it, and I wonder if it might depend on things like OS, filesystem etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about ENOSPC. It indicates that the write failed, and that reason why it failed has something do with the device not having enough free space to complete the operation. It doesn't leave the file descriptor in a bad or undefined state. The file descriptor remains in the same state as before the call. You can safely keep trying as much you want.

Note that you should be prepared for short writes. If a write system call doesn't have enough space to complete the operation instead of failing with ENOSPC, it can write as much as can and return successfully. In that the case the return value will indicate the actual number of bytes written.